# Create a new view pulling form multiple table but continuously receive "missing keyword" error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a new view that contains customer first name, last name, order number, and order total for each order.

First name and last name are pulled from the customer table. Order# and order total are pulled from order items. They do not have any overlapping columns:

```
CREATE VIEW order_totals AS
    SELECT firstname, 
           lastname, 
           order#,
           TO_CHAR(SUM(quantity*paideach), '$999.99') AS "Order Total"
    FROM customers 
     JOIN orders USING (customer#) 
     JOIN orderitems USING order#
    GROUP BY firstname, lastname, order#;
```

Comment: You have a columns named order# and customer#? With the pound-signs? I didn't even know that was possible, but it's probably bad practice to have non-alphanumeric characters in a column or table name. Anyways, with the 'Using' clause, you need to have parenthesese around the variables. You need to add them around the last joined table, like `JOIN orderitems USING (order#)`

Comment: @JoshEller - unquoted database identifiers can legally contain alphanumeric, underscore, dollar and hash characters. It's [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129). Although I agree it's a little unorthodox to use `#` instead of `_id` or whatever.

Comment: Ahhh right silly mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @ReeDFence - consistency is a virtue when writing code. You formatted the two `using` clauses differently. If you had formatted them both the same you would have resolved your bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW order_totals AS
SELECT firstname, lastname, order#, TO_CHAR(SUM(quantity*paideach), '$999.99') AS "Order Total"
FROM customers JOIN orders USING (customer#) JOIN orderitems USING (order#)
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, order#;
```

Adding () around order# should be the reason your missing a keyword. In your second join.

Edit: oops josh got to it before me :x